# Get accessible text/label of the currently focused item

Tags: java, eclipse, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I am developing an eclipse plugin and I am using a custom screen reader with it. I want to make the complete application of eclipse accessible by narrating the “accessible text/label” of the currently focused object.

For example if the focus is on File, the screen reader will narrate File, if the focus is on a sub menu the screen reader will narrate that particular menu. Similarly all dialogue boxes should be accessible as well.

My issue is that eclipse core is all in binary files and therefore I cannot detect when a particular control gets focused.

I tried decompiling the binary files, modifying them and then integrating these recompiled modified files but to no avail as eclipse stopped working after this.

I want an API or anything that will allow me to detect the current focused element and then return the “accessible text/label” of that particular element so I can further send it to my screen reader for narration.

Comment: Eclipse/SWT has an accessibilty API for screen readers see [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Accessibility)

Comment: This API is mostly about supporting accessibility in custom controls. What I want is to make the complete eclipse accessible by detecing focus on a particular item and then passing its text/label to my custom screen reader.